# last queries mysql v$sql

Tags: mysql

i have oracle background,
i am looking for oracle v$sql view in mysql in order to see last queries has been run on all sessions in database

how can i see this in mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature on MySQL.  The best thing you can do is study the server logs with query logging enabled.